# Generated ffmpeg video seems to be not a real video file

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I try to create a video with `ffmpeg` and save it to the device with `gallery_saver` package for Flutter.

The `ffmpeg` command works well and the video is created. But `GallerySaver` does not save it. As result I get no error, but a `false` boolean for the `success` argument.

This is the `ffmpeg` output. Is this a valid video mp4 file?

```
Restarted application in 683ms.
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mStart
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mInit state
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mBuild
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mDevice locale de_DE
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mLoad asset from assets/translations
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mInit Localization Delegate
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mInit provider
[38;5;244m[Easy Localization] [39;49mLoad Localization Delegate
flutter: Loading flutter-ffmpeg.
flutter: Loaded flutter-ffmpeg-ios-arm64.
flutter: ffmpeg version git-2020-01-25-fd11dd500 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/ios-arm64-apple-darwin/ffmpeg --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target aarch64-ios-darwin -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_BUILD_DATE=20200125 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --enable-neon --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-small --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-coreimage --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.102 / 58. 65.102
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
Input #0, mp3, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/melodic_slow.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : LAME 32bits version 3.99.5 (http://lame.sf.net)
    TLEN            : 134072
  Duration: 00:02:14.11, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/Memories-8c4a9c20-f9b8-11ea-b262-853cab0c1dfa.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:00.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 55269 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 4032x3024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 55338 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
using SAR=1/1
using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
profile High, level 6.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/Memories-8da54a20-f9b8-11ea-b216-7df10c3fe45b.mp4':
  Metadata:
    TLEN            : 134072
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 4032x3024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.102 aac
frame=    4 fps=2.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1028kB time=00:00:00.18 bitrate=45323.6kbits/s speed=0.115x
video:1023kB audio:3kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.143686%
frame I:1     Avg QP:24.74  size:488633
frame P:3     Avg QP:23.50  size:186193
mb I  I16..4:  3.0% 90.0%  7.1%
mb P  I16..4: 28.7% 67.4%  3.8%  P16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
8x8 transform intra:73.1% inter:60.0%
coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 41.8% 29.7% 8.7% inter: 3.7% 1.7% 0.3%
i16 v,h,dc,p: 53% 33%  3% 11%
i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 22% 22%  4%  4%  3%  7%  4%  5%
i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 30% 12%  4%  5%  4%  8%  4%  5%
i8c dc,h,v,p: 70% 18%  9%  3%
Weighted P-Frames: Y:33.3% UV:33.3%
ref P L0:  1.4%  0.0% 95.5%  0.0%  3.1%
kb/s:50266.18
Qavg: 134.735
flutter: ffmpeg version git-2020-01-25-fd11dd500
flutter:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
flutter:
flutter:   built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
flutter:   configuration: --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/ios-arm64-apple-darwin/ffmpeg --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target aarch64-ios-darwin -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_BUILD_DATE=20200125 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --enable-neon --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-small --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-coreimage --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv
flutter:   libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
flutter:   libavcodec     58. 65.102 / 58. 65.102
flutter:   libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
flutter:   libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
flutter:   libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
flutter:   libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
flutter:   libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
flutter: Input #0, image2, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/img%04d.jpg':
flutter:   Duration:
flutter: 00:00:00.20
flutter: , start:
flutter: 0.000000
flutter: , bitrate:
flutter: N/A
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: : Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4032x3024 [SAR 72:72 DAR 4:3]
flutter: ,
flutter: 25 tbr,
flutter: 25 tbn,
flutter: 25 tbc
flutter:
flutter: Stream mapping:
flutter:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
flutter:  (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
flutter:
flutter: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
flutter: sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
flutter: deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
flutter: using SAR=1/1
flutter: using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
flutter: profile High, level 6.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
flutter: 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
flutter: Output #0, mp4, to '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/Memories-f2ae4f70-f9b8-11ea-bb69-c999fb23197b.mp4':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: Lavf58.35.101
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 4032x3024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1
flutter: ,
flutter: 24 fps,
flutter: 12288 tbn,
flutter: 24 tbc
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: Lavc58.65.102 libx264
flutter:
flutter:     Side data:
flutter:
flutter: cpb:
flutter: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0
flutter: vbv_delay: N/A
flutter:
flutter: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
flutter: sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
flutter: deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
flutter: sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
flutter: deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
flutter: frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
flutter: frame=    5 fps=1.8 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1485kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=145828.4kbits/s speed=0.0305x
flutter: video:1484kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
flutter: 0.059291%
flutter:
flutter: frame I:1     Avg QP:24.93  size:366082
flutter: frame P:4     Avg QP:24.17  size:288219
flutter: mb I  I16..4:  8.6% 81.4% 10.1%
flutter: mb P  I16..4: 21.7% 71.4%  6.6%  P16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
flutter: 8x8 transform intra:73.6% inter:79.9%
flutter: coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 48.6% 33.8% 12.6% inter: 33.4% 41.4% 0.0%
flutter: i16 v,h,dc,p: 53% 31%  4% 12%
flutter: i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 18% 24%  5%  4%  4%  6%  5%  5%
flutter: i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 23% 14%  7%  6%  5%  7%  5%  5%
flutter: i8c dc,h,v,p: 67% 17% 12%  4%
flutter: Weighted P-Frames: Y:25.0% UV:25.0%
flutter: ref P L0: 43.6%  0.2% 55.0%  0.0%  1.1%
flutter: kb/s:58327.98
flutter: ffmpeg version git-2020-01-25-fd11dd500
flutter:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
flutter:
flutter:   built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
flutter:   configuration: --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/ios-arm64-apple-darwin/ffmpeg --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target aarch64-ios-darwin -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_BUILD_DATE=20200125 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --enable-neon --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-small --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-coreimage --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv
flutter:   libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
flutter:   libavcodec     58. 65.102 / 58. 65.102
flutter:   libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
flutter:   libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
flutter:   libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
flutter:   libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
flutter:   libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
flutter: Input #0, mp3, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/melodic_slow.mp3':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: LAME 32bits version 3.99.5 (http://lame.sf.net)
flutter:
flutter:     TLEN            :
flutter: 134072
flutter:
flutter:   Duration:
flutter: 00:02:14.11
flutter: , start:
flutter: 0.025057
flutter: , bitrate:
flutter: 320 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: : Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: LAME3.99r
flutter:
flutter: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/Memories-f2ae4f70-f9b8-11ea-bb69-c999fb23197b.mp4':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     major_brand     :
flutter: isom
flutter:
flutter:     minor_version   :
flutter: 512
flutter:
flutter:     compatible_brands:
flutter: isomiso2avc1mp41
flutter:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: Lavf58.35.101
flutter:
flutter:   Duration:
flutter: 00:00:00.21
flutter: , start:
flutter: 0.000000
flutter: , bitrate:
flutter: 58202 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #1:0
flutter: (und)
flutter: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 4032x3024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 58353 kb/s
flutter: ,
flutter: 24 fps,
flutter: 24 tbr,
flutter: 12288 tbn,
flutter: 48 tbc
flutter:  (default)
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       handler_name    :
flutter: VideoHandler
flutter:
flutter: Stream mapping:
flutter:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:0
flutter:  (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
flutter:
flutter:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1
flutter:  (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
flutter:
flutter: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
flutter: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
flutter: sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
flutter: using SAR=1/1
flutter: using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
flutter: profile High, level 6.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
flutter: 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
flutter: Output #0, mp4, to '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/Memories-f475c900-f9b8-11ea-9b26-639f1e3575c9.mp4':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     TLEN            :
flutter: 134072
flutter:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: Lavf58.35.101
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: (und)
flutter: : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 4032x3024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1
flutter: ,
flutter: 24 fps,
flutter: 12288 tbn,
flutter: 24 tbc
flutter:  (default)
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       handler_name    :
flutter: VideoHandler
flutter:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: Lavc58.65.102 libx264
flutter:
flutter:     Side data:
flutter:
flutter: cpb:
flutter: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0
flutter: vbv_delay: N/A
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:1
flutter: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: Lavc58.65.102 aac
flutter:
flutter: frame=    5 fps=2.4 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1328kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=52040.4kbits/s speed= 0.1x
flutter: video:1323kB audio:3kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
flutter: 0.112379%
flutter:
flutter: frame I:1     Avg QP:23.27  size:307048
flutter: frame P:4     Avg QP:23.71  size:261707
flutter: mb I  I16..4: 12.0% 84.4%  3.6%
flutter: mb P  I16..4: 21.8% 73.5%  4.6%  P16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
flutter: 8x8 transform intra:75.8% inter:82.6%
flutter: coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 43.8% 33.2% 11.5% inter: 18.9% 20.3% 0.2%
flutter: i16 v,h,dc,p: 52% 33%  4% 11%
flutter: i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 20% 24%  4%  4%  3%  6%  4%  5%
flutter: i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 28% 12%  4%  5%  4%  7%  5%  5%
flutter: i8c dc,h,v,p: 67% 18% 12%  4%
flutter: Weighted P-Frames: Y:25.0% UV:25.0%
flutter: ref P L0: 24.0%  0.4% 73.9%  0.0%  1.8%
flutter: kb/s:51988.88
flutter: Qavg: 137.086
flutter: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F90BA97-59E6-4632-B86A-2B0C1C552273/Library/Caches/Memories-f475c900-f9b8-11ea-9b26-639f1e3575c9.mp4
flutter: Success argument is: false
```

This are my `ffmpeg` commands:

**First I create a video from images in a folder**

`-r $settingsFps -i $tempPath/img%04d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -y -an -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -pix_fmt yuv420p $tempPath/$videoFileName.mp4`

**Than I add audio to the video**

`-i ${finalSong.path} -i $videoPath -shortest $tempPath/$newVideoFileName.mp4`

Comment: FFMPEG creates a new file.

Comment: What do you exactly want so say? :) Yes. It creates a file in output `$tempPath/$newVideoFileName.mp4`.

Comment: The resolution is very high. Gallerysaver may not support it.

Comment: How could I change the resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Output is only 5 frames

Make the video and add the audio in the same command. You can loop the images so it makes a proper length in relation to the audio:

```
-y -framerate $settingsFps -loop 1 -i $tempPath/img%04d.jpg -i ${finalSong.path} -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -movflags +faststart $tempPath/$newVideoFileName.mp4
```

Alternatively, use [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer) to time the images. Or set an input `-framerate` and an appropriate output framerate via [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) filter or `-r` option to provide the proper duration.

## 4032x3024 is big

Your device/player may not like it and it will take longer to encode. Refer to the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale). Simple example to scale to 1280 pixels wide, and height will be scaled to preserve the aspect ratio **and** be divisible by 2 (required by libx264 when outputting yuv420p).

```
-y -framerate $settingsFps -loop 1 -i $tempPath/img%04d.jpg -i ${finalSong.path} -vf "scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -movflags +faststart $tempPath/$newVideoFileName.mp4
```